# Extend QScrollArea when using QSplitter

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QScrollArea that contains a QHBoxLayout and inside of it a QSplitter with multiple QWidgets. I wish to extend the widgets with the splitters between them.

My problem is I need to set a minimum size on the widges. If I do that the splitters are useless (they do not perform any actions). This is normal because I can not minimize the other widgets to give space to the one I wish to extend.

Is there any way to push all the widgets outside the initial area and to extend the scrollarea or something like that?